# как в коде установить в примечании ссылку на другой участок кода, класс или метод?

Tags: android

как в коде установить в примечании ссылку на другой участок кода, класс или метод, чтобы можно было перейти по ней?
пробовал так но перейти туда не получается

```
if(Earth.isDestroyed){ //this param calc this -> class.Phisics.calcStateEarth();
   ...
}
```

Comment: Наверное только стандартные возможности тегов JavaDoc : @see , {@link} что не особо помогает. По крайней мере другого в исходниках Android я не встречал

Comment: Не совсем понятно когда это может понадобится.

Comment: подробные комменты понадобилось писать при передаче программы в другую команду разработчиков. Вместо длительных описаний проще послать в нужный класс а лучше метод.